# Serde serialize with proxy type for remote object

Tags: serialization, rust, serde

How can I create a serializer proxy object for a remote type with Serde? Here is a minimal example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=234e6374f1907fbb8d77ed5fdfd20c62)):

```
use serde; // 1.0.104
use serde_json; // 1.0.48

struct Foo {
    bar: u8,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { bar: 10 }
    }

    pub fn val(&self) -> u8 {
        self.bar
    }
}

#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
#[serde(remote = "Foo")]
struct Bar {
    #[serde(getter = "Foo::val")]
    val: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new();
    let res = serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap();
    println!("{}", res);
}
```

It cannot find the implementation:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: _IMPL_SERIALIZE_FOR_Bar::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:27:37
     |
27   |     let res = serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap();
     |                                     ^^^^ the trait `_IMPL_SERIALIZE_FOR_Bar::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `Foo`
     | 
    ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde_json-1.0.48/src/ser.rs:2233:8
     |
2233 |     T: Serialize,
     |        --------- required by this bound in `serde_json::ser::to_string`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#[serde(remote = "Foo")]` cannot break the orphan rule so does not really implement the trait for the type `Foo`.

You must use it with `#[serde(with = "...")]`.

An easy way to do this is to create a small wrapper for serialization:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
struct FooWrapper<'a>(#[serde(with = "Bar")] &'a Foo);
```

and use it as `serde_json::to_string(&FooWrapper(&foo))` ([permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da1f39b8deb6f2a07bb035c654370905)).

This will serialize `Foo` as you expect using the remote definition `Bar`.

For deserialization, you can use `Bar::deserialize` and you will get a `Foo` directly.

See also:

- [serde's documentation: Deriving De/Serialize for type in a different crate](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html)

Comment: Aaah, I was afraid this would be the case. But this solves all my questions. Thanks!