# How to serialize a struct from a dependency using serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to serialize a struct using `derive`:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    txt: ResolveResult<TxtLookup>
}
```

[`ResolveResult`](https://docs.rs/trust-dns-resolver/latest/trust_dns_resolver/error/type.ResolveResult.html) and [`TxtLookup`](https://docs.rs/trust-dns-resolver/latest/trust_dns_resolver/lookup/struct.TxtLookup.html) are from trust-dns-resolver 0.20.3. I'm using serde 1.0 for the serialization.

I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `TxtLookup: Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     txt: ResolveResult<TxtLookup>
   |     ^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `TxtLookup`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Serialize` for `std::result::Result<TxtLookup, ResolveError>`
   = note: required by `_::_serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ResolveError: Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     txt: ResolveResult<TxtLookup>
   |     ^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `ResolveError`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Serialize` for `std::result::Result<TxtLookup, ResolveError>`
   = note: required by `_::_serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
```

How do I implement serialization for `TxtLookup` and `ResolveError`? I am new to Rust so its difficult to comprehend.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Serde serialize with proxy type for remote object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61480342/155423); [Is there a way for me to use #[derive\] on a struct or enum from a library without editing the actual library's source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48267016/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Looks like that is what I was finding. thanks. @Shepmaster